# a disk moved from an old computer requires a root user to be mounted, why?

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, chown

I had a data disk on my previous computer (*Debian 9*) accessible to me, the user `marc`.

Then I bought a new computer (*Debian 10*), and the reseller put that disk among others, that was immediately discovered, but he defined me as the user `lebihan` (instead of `marc`, and the `marc` user doesn't exist anymore).

So when I enter my session, the data disk is here (named `datapartition` on `/dev/sda1`) and if I double click on it, I have to enter the root password to access it for the first time :

[image]

Then everything is fine, I managed to do a link so that `data` folder leads to it, with the user `lebihan`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 lebihan lebihan    28 avril 29  2021 data -> /media/lebihan/datapartition
```

(and `/media/lebihan/datapartition` is also `lebihan:lebihan`)

All `/dev/sd*` devices are `root:root`,
and my `/etc/fstab` content is this one :

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=26f4213d-da74-4635-9328-b1223ecb8183 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=782A-1AC8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=9b2f067b-17d4-4616-bedb-38772ad73158 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I can't figure what I should change (and where) to allow direct access with user `lebihan` to my data disk.
I guess that it still has an owner `marc` declared somewhere? But I can't be sure of that.

What should I do or check?

Answer (score 2):

Mounting a filesystem is a privileged operation so it always needs root privileges. There is an exception for external drives, but for internal drives your system will ask for your passphrase (passphrase of a root/sudo user) if the device is not in fstab.

If you want the disk to be mounted without asking for a passphrase you need to add it to `/etc/fstab` with the `users` mount option (see [mount man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) for more details about the option).

So you should add something like

```
UUID=<uuid of /dev/sda1>  <mountpoint>   <filesystem>    defaults,users,nofail    0  0
```

you can use `lsblk -f` to get UUID and filesystem type for `/dev/sda1`. You can also use GNOME Disks to add the fstab entry from GUI if you don't want to edit it manually.

The user name doesn't really matter here. You are asked for a passphrase to mount the drive, this isn't based on the filesystem owner. After you mount the filesystem, the owner of the files and directories on the filesystem is important, but the file permissions after aren't based on the user name, but on the user ID, which (assuming you had only one user on the system) will be same. So if you see the owner of the files in `/media/lebihan/datapartition` is `lebihan`, you don't need to change anything.